# Creating JSON Post In Angular 2

Tags: json, angular, auth0

I am using Auth0 in my angular2 app and once the user logs in the auth0 service sends a response that holds the user profile information.

The response can look many different ways depending on the method of login the user selects. I am only wanting to split off the email address in the response.

This is a typical response,

```
Object
clientID
:
"skdjcbjlwrjlw"
created_at
:
"2016-10-15T06:03:44.636Z"
email
:
"nick@example.com"
email_verified
:
true
family_name
:
"Walker"
gender
:
"male"
given_name
:
"Paul"
global_client_id
:
"ojwebcvjoweojewhc"
identities
:
Array[1]
locale
:
"en"
name
:
"Paul Walker"
nickname
:
"nick"
picture
:
"https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/photo.jpg"
updated_at
:
"2016-11-21T22:29:33.158Z"
user_id
:
"google-oauth2|102515181977826170152"
__proto__
:
Object
```

Now when I receive that response I split the email address off like this,

1. I created a class to hold the email address,

   `export class User {
         constructor(
           public email: string,
         ) {  }
       }`
2. I instantiate the object,
   `user: Object;`
3. I move the email from the profile object into the `user`

`this.user = profile.email;`

The problem at this point is I need the email to be in JSON format. So I use,

```
var email = JSON.stringify(this.user);
```

But when I `console.log(email);` 
I get myemail@example.com instead of json.

So at this point,

```
 console.log(profile); // outputs json of whole profile
        this.user = profile.email;
        console.log(this.user); // outputs just the email address
         var email = JSON.stringify(this.user); 
        console.log(email);   // expects json gets email@example.com
```

I need the `email` to be actual json. Am I not using `JSON.stringify(this.user);` correctly?

Comment: 2. is not instantiating anything. It declares a variable of type Object. 3 assigns profile.email, which is probably a String, to that variable. If user is supposed to be a User, its type should be User, not Object. And you shouldn't assign a string to that variable. To create an instance of User, the syntax is `new User(theEmail)`. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Comment: Thanks man. Instantly works. I feel guilty now for asking. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>For greater visibility I'm including the comment from JB Nizet as a community wiki answer.</sub>

---

**Step 2**, is not instantiating anything. It declares a variable of type Object.

**Step 3**, assigns `profile.email`, which is probably a string, to that variable. If `user` is supposed to be a `User`, its type should be `User`, not `Object`. And you shouldn't assign a string to that variable. To create an instance of `User`, the syntax is `new User(theEmail)`.

Check [typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) for reference.